# How to redirect user to another page using javascript in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I want to redirect the user to another page only after displaying a success message. The code below redirects to the another page even if the page is refreshed without submitting any data.

*Code Snippet*

```
<?php
// We will store our status message later
$message = '';

// Let's check form submitted
if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'submit' ) {

    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $phone = $_POST['number'];

    $message_text = $_POST['address'];


        if (isset($_POST['action'])) 
        {   

            // Validate required fields 
            if( $name == '' || $email == '' || $message_text == '' ){
                $message = "<p class=\"error\">Please fill out all required fields.</p>";  
            }


            // send email after validation
            else {

                // Email will be sent at this email
                $mailto = 'nepstarditsolutions@gmail.com';

                // Let's create html email format 
                // (You can use html in this email format)

                // Email headers
                $headers = "From: " . strip_tags( $email ) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags( $email ) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

                // Email body
                $message = "<html><body>";
                $message .= "<h3>Contact Info: </h3>";
                $message .= "<p><strong>Name: </strong> ". strip_tags( $name ) . "</p>\r\n";
                $message .= "<p><strong>Email: </strong> ". strip_tags( $email ) . "</p>\r\n";

                $message .= "<p><strong>Contact Number: </strong> ". strip_tags( $phone ) . "</p>\r\n";
                $message .= "<p><strong>Alternate Email: </strong> ". strip_tags( $_POST['altemail'] ) . "</p>\r\n";
                $message .= "<p><strong>Hosting Package: </strong> ". strip_tags( $_POST['cradio'] ) . "</p>\r\n";

                $message .= "<p><strong>Address: </strong>". strip_tags( $message_text ) . "</p>\r\n";
                $message .= "</body></html>";



                // Email subject
                $subject = "Contact Info from ".$name;

                // Send email
                $mail_status = @mail( $mailto, $subject, $message, $headers );

                if( $mail_status ){
                    $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Quotation submitted Successfully ! </div>';   
                }
                else {
                    $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error in sending the Quotation ! </div>';  
                }

            }
        }   
}
?>
```

**I need help in 2 things**

1. Success message should be displayed for 2 seconds (before the redirect).
2. How to redirect using JS in php?

Comment: <script>
setTimeout("location.href = 'https://imjo.in/Z8MSuX';",5000);
</script>

This is the redirection code which I have !

Comment: What do you want to do if the message is unsuccessful? Stay on the same page? Also, why can't you just use php to redirect to the other page?

Comment: Well I don't have much knowledge about PHP ! But yes if the form is unsuccessful the user should stay on same page and the message should be displayed... Displaying the message is already done in the php code. So Now I am only looking for the script which will redirect the user after successful submission and will not redirect if its unsuccessful.

Comment: I suggest that you look up `header()` in PHP. Also, you might consider refreshing the page if the message is unsuccessful. Of course, you can simply echo your script as Tom has it in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Standard "vanilla" JavaScript way to redirect a page**

You can use the code below to redirect the user after form submission code.

```
if( $mail_status ){
    echo "
        <script>
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = 'http://www.example.com/newlocation';
            }, 2000);
        </script>
    ";
}
```

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) on how `setTimeout` works

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Ankush ! Well my query is... My form gets submitted successfully but after that successful message itself it should redirect the user to other page... And if the submission fails its should not redirect.


You can check the page here https://www.nepstard.com/demo/shared-quotation.php

Comment: I just updated the answer, this should resolve your issue (Y)

Comment: Let me check this too !

Comment: Since you want to redirect after 2 seconds, code updated! Please mention this point in the question for other users of SO

Comment: https://www.nepstard.com/demo/silver-shared-quotation.php


Well the above code is working perfect but now its messing up the css after successful message !. Check the link which I have given in this reply. I have kept the delay time to 5 seconds.

Comment: You can see on this link even after submission its not disturbing the css

https://www.nepstard.com/demo/shared-quotation.php


Whereas on the new link https://www.nepstard.com/demo/silver-shared-quotation.php

its disturbing the css... Just added the settimeout code nothing else.